# Turtlebot spinning in place + not going straight when speeding up simulation

Tags: ros, gazebo, turtlebot, spinning, kobuki

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
As I show in the videos above, the Turtlebot is spins around itself a bit, which could affect the direction when I try to go straight. When the real time factor (simulation speed) is normal the robot makes an acceptable straight line, but when the simulation is set to maximum the robot clearly turns to the right. This strange behaviour does not happen in empty worlds, just when the robot is inside a model. Any possible solution to this issue?

Nestor

---

Video1 - Spining around itself
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LdImDUFFOck&feature=youtu.be

Video 2 - Trying to go straight -  in 0:40 normal speed is tested
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ltf0eb4ZMcE&feature=youtu.be

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/243549/turtlebot-spinning-in-place-+-not-going-straight-when-speeding-up-simulation/) by [nzlz](https://answers.ros.org/users/27382/nzlz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2016-09-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It appears that you're speeding up gazebo to the point that the physics simulation is no longer converging to an accurate result. This can happen when the granularity of the simulation gets too great or the number of iterations for the solver are inadequate.

In general it's expected that if you speed up the physics that the accuracy drops. I suspect that this is something that can be tuned to run at the speeds you want w/o drifting turns. But to get more advice on this I'd recommend asking on http://answers.gazebosim.org/questions/ since this really is an issue releated to simulation. They can probably help you tune the parameters for the model. As you've noticed this is related to both the robot model as well as the world model and how much computational time it takes for both.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2016-09-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0